# Recursive SQL tree optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, db2

I am currently struggling with a performance problem on my Db2 database. I have written SQL which builds a complete tree from a source table. In the result you can see all possible ways from parent to child, grandchild, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE SOURCE_TABLE (
            PARENT_ID VARCHAR(12),
            CHILD_ID VARCHAR(12)
);
 
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) VALUES (NULL, 'A');
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) VALUES (NULL, 'B');
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) VALUES (NULL, 'C');
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) VALUES ('A', 'A_1');
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) VALUES ('A_1', 'A_1_2');
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) VALUES ('B', 'B_1');
```

| PARENT_ID | CHILD_ID |
| --- | --- |
| (null) | A |
| (null) | B |
| (null) | C |
| A | A_1 |
| A_1 | A_1_2 |
| B | B_1 |

And my code:

```
WITH PARENTS(ID) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_ID
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE
    WHERE PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
),
LVL_TREE(LVL, DIM_PARENT_ID, DIM_CHILD_ID) AS
(
     SELECT 1, PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID
     FROM SOURCE_TABLE
     WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT L.LVL + 1, Q.PARENT_ID, Q.CHILD_ID
     FROM LVL_TREE L, SOURCE_TABLE Q
     WHERE Q.PARENT_ID = L.DIM_CHILD_ID
),         
TREE(DIM_PARENT_ID, DIM_CHILD_ID, DIM_PARENT_LVL, DIM_CHILD_LVL, DIM_LVL, DIM_TYPE) AS
(
    SELECT DIM_PARENT_ID, DIM_CHILD_ID, LVL-1, LVL, 1,
    CASE WHEN DIM_CHILD_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PARENTS) THEN 'S' ELSE 'B' END AS DIM_TYPE
    FROM LVL_TREE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.DIM_PARENT_ID, Q.CHILD_ID, T.DIM_PARENT_LVL, T.DIM_PARENT_LVL + T.DIM_LVL + 1, T.DIM_LVL + 1,
    CASE WHEN Q.CHILD_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PARENTS) THEN 'S' ELSE 'B' END AS DIM_TYPE
    FROM TREE T, SOURCE_TABLE Q
    WHERE T.DIM_PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL AND Q.PARENT_ID = T.DIM_CHILD_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DIM_CHILD_ID, DIM_CHILD_ID, LVL, LVL, 0, 'B'
    FROM LVL_TREE WHERE DIM_CHILD_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM PARENTS)
)
SELECT
    DIM_PARENT_ID,
    DIM_CHILD_ID,
    DIM_PARENT_LVL,
    DIM_CHILD_LVL,
    DIM_LVL,
    DIM_TYPE
FROM TREE
WHERE DIM_PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
```

My code works perfectly and show correct result:

| DIM_PARENT_ID | DIM_CHILD_ID | DIM_PARENT_LVL | DIM_CHILD_LVL | DIM_LVL | DIM_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A_1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | S |
| A | A_1_2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | B |
| A_1 | A_1_2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | B |
| A_1_2 | A_1_2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | B |
| B | B_1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | B |
| B_1 | B_1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | B |
| C | C | 1 | 1 | 0 | B |

Problem is, my SOURCE_TABLE have over 1.5 Mio rows and even after 20 hours I get no result. Any optimization suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You probably have some loops in your data where A is a parent of B, but B is a parent of A.  This is only the simplest example.  To detect, you should list_agg() your parent keys and check that the current level is not contained in it anywhere.

Comment: You may want to look at ways to represent the transisitive closure of the tree, instead of recursively determine it. Search for nested sets, materialized path and transitive closure table. In the last case you can maintain the transitive closure via triggers on your source_table

Comment: @laz-karimov, is your tree limited in height?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini no

Answer (score 1):

Is this really all there is to the source table?

```
CREATE TABLE SOURCE_TABLE (
    PARENT_ID VARCHAR(12),
    CHILD_ID VARCHAR(12)
);
```

I mean no indexes, no keys, everything can be null, etc?

Generating a small tree like:

```
insert into source_table (child_id, parent_id) 
with gen(n) as ( values 1 
                 union all 
                 select n+1 from gen where n<10000 
) select n::varchar(12)
       , case when n<>sqrt(n) then sqrt(n)::int::varchar(12) end 
  from gen
```

and then running your query takes for ever:

```
real    0m38,704s
user    0m0,232s
sys     0m0,339s
```

adding two indexes like:

```
create index x1 on SOURCE_TABLE(PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID) 
allow reverse scans 
collect sampled detailed statistics

create index x2 on SOURCE_TABLE(CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID) 
allow reverse scans 
collect sampled detailed statistics
```

improves the situation:

```
real    0m0,983s
user    0m0,226s
sys     0m0,321s
```

but you should rethink your design:

```
 CREATE TABLE SOURCE_TABLE (
    CHILD_ID VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    PARENT_ID VARCHAR(12)
        REFERENCES SOURCE_TABLE (CHILD_ID)
);
```

is a start. If you want to take it even further, consider dividing your table into two, say:

```
CREATE TABLE TREE_NODES
( NODE_ID VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT PK_NODES PRIMARY KEY (NODE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TREE_STRUCTURES
( NODE_ID VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
, PARENT_NODE_ID VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_TREE_STRUCTURE ON TREE_STRUCTURES
    (NODE_ID)
INCLUDE (PARENT_NODE_ID)
ALLOW REVERSE SCANS
COLLECT SAMPLED DETAILED STATISTICS;

CREATE INDEX X01_TREE_STRUCTURE ON TREE_STRUCTURES
    (PARENT_NODE_ID, NODE_ID)
ALLOW REVERSE SCANS
COLLECT SAMPLED DETAILED STATISTICS;

ALTER TABLE TREE_STRUCTURES ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TREE_STRUCTURE 
    PRIMARY KEY (NODE_ID);

ALTER TABLE TREE_STRUCTURES ADD CONSTRAINT FK1_NODES 
      FOREIGN KEY (NODE_ID) REFERENCES TREE_NODES (NODE_ID);

ALTER TABLE TREE_STRUCTURES ADD CONSTRAINT FK2_NODES
      FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_NODE_ID) REFERENCES TREE_STRUCTURES (NODE_ID);
```

You can probably improve your query as well, but it is a bit difficult to tell without knowing what the result represents

Comment: Thanks a lot. Of course I have indexes in a source table, that was just an example. Unfortunately I cannot change the source table, because it is filled by another department. I was thinking of improving my query, since this is the only option

Comment: What does S and B stand for? Do you need the whole transitive closure of the tree?

Comment: Yes, these fields are needed and make the query heavy with subselects. S for between connection and B ist for leaf connection

Comment: You know that: `select x.child_id, x.child_id, 'B' from SOURCE_TABLE x left join source_table y on x.child_id = y.parent_id where y.parent_id is null` is the 'B' nodes, all the others are 'S' nodes

Comment: Unfortunately not, because there are also other 'B'. For example A->B->C, AB = S, BC = B, AC = B. Not only direct Children are 'B'

Comment: Does not really matter, just put B on all leaf nodes. But don't do it in the recursive part

Comment: But how? from my ABC example, AB and AC are generated in the recursive part and they are 'S' and 'B' respectively

Comment: Example: `SELECT
    DIM_PARENT_ID,
    DIM_CHILD_ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LVL_TREE y WHERE y.DIM_CHILD_ID = x.DIM_PARENT_ID) AS DIM_PARENT_LVL,
    LVL AS DIM_CHILD_LVL,
    1 AS DIM_LVL,
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE y WHERE x.DIM_CHILD_ID = y.PARENT_ID )
    THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END AS DIM_TYPE
FROM LVL_TREE x
;
`

Comment: Sorry, but I still think it will return S for grandchild connection. For ABC it will return AB=S, BC=B, and AC=S (but must be B)